# Monitoring the Airflow web server when using Google Cloud Composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

How can I monitor the Airflow web server when using Google Cloud Composer? If the web server goes down or crashes due to an error, I would like to receive an alert.

Comment: The web service for Composer is backed by the same technology behind [App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/). This means the web process should be fairly fault-tolerant and the service should be looking after the web server process. So, while this may be a common issue for non-managed Airflow, it should be less of a concern with Cloud Composer.

Are there cases where the web service has failed in a Composer environment?

Comment: I don't have any such case, but i want to make sure that my service is running fine.
Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Stackdriver Monitoring**: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/monitoring-environments. Alerts can also be set in Stackdriver.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, fine-grained metrics for the Airflow web server are not exported to Stackdriver, so it cannot be monitored like other resources in a Cloud Composer environment (such as the GKE cluster, GCE instances, etc). This is because the web server [runs in a tenant project](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/overview#architecture) alongside your main project that most of your environment's resources live in.

However, web server logs for Airflow in Composer are now [visible in Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/release-notes#march_11_2019) as of March 11, 2019. That means for the time being, you can configure [logs-based metrics](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/) for the web server log (matching on lines that contain `Traceback`, etc).